# Change from a German dependent visa to blue card?

Tags: germany, blue-card, dependent-visa

My partner is on dependent visa with me and recently secured a job in another city. I have two questions regarding this.

1. Can she just move to another city (to Berlin from Niedersachen) for her job?
2. Is it possible to get an independent status for her, or a blue card, as she has a job offer now?
3. She is having problems proving that she falls under Group 21, 221 or 25 for reduced requirements for a Blue card. How can she provide the proof for that? Is a certificate from her employer enough?